# Jquery counter inside php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, counter

I'm a little stuck with my code. My script can add and remove a textbox. I want to give the value of the textboxes with a session with PHP. I am using a counter to add and remove the textboxes. That works all fine but I have no clue how to do that with sessions when adding a textbox.

When adding a textbox:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label><b>Pagina #'+ counter + ' : </b></label><br>' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:20%; display: inline-block;" name="textbox' + counter +
    '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
```

This is what I want:

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['textbox' + counter + ''];?>"
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qhzfn54s/1/)

Comment: JS can not access the session directly. So you either need to have all relevant data in the page source in a form that JS can read (array/object; JSON) from the start, or use AJAX to make a request to the server that returns the necessary bit of data.

Comment: But is there no way to do it without AJAX?

Comment: You do know what “or” means, right?